# Android deeplinks not getting url

Tags: java, android, android-deep-link

I am adding deeplinks to my Android  but I am not getting the URL when I click on https://example.com/myvalues, while When I click on myScheme://example.com/myvalues  (Scheme is myScheme)

Here are my intent-filters:

**AndroidManifest.xml**

```xml
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
    <data android:host="example.com" android:scheme="http" />
</intent-filter>
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
    <data android:host="example.com" android:scheme="https" />
</intent-filter>
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
    <data android:scheme="myScheme" />
</intent-filter>
<intent-filter android:autoVerify="true">
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
    <data android:host="example.com" android:pathPrefix="/" android:scheme="https" />
    <data android:host=" " android:pathPrefix="/" android:scheme=" " />
    <data android:host=" " android:pathPrefix="/" android:scheme=" " />
    <data android:host=" " android:pathPrefix="/" android:scheme=" " />
    <data android:host=" " android:pathPrefix="/" android:scheme=" " />
</intent-filter>
<intent-filter android:autoVerify="true">
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
    <data android:scheme="https"
                    android:host="example.com"
                    android:pathPrefix="/" />
</intent-filter>
<intent-filter android:autoVerify="true" >
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
    <!-- Accepts URIs that begin with "example://gizmos” -->
    <data android:scheme="myScheme"
                    android:host="example.com" />
</intent-filter>
```

And my Java code is

```java
final String intentString = intent.getDataString();

// read intent
String action = intent.getAction();
Uri url = intent.getData();
```

In url I am getting,

> url : "myScheme://",
> host:"",
> queryString: ""

Can anyone please help me to get what I am missing or debug this ?

I have tried almost all example and guides on blogs and also tried with the official documentations.